# Replacements for swear words

Tags: terminology, profanity

Is there a term for the following phenomenon or the words that are used in this way: One starts to utter a swear word, but continues to form an innocent sounding word. Examples from German are *Sack Zement* instead of *Sakrament* and *Scheibenkleister* or *Scheibenhonig* instead of *Scheiße*.

Comment: I guess it's a kind of bowdlerisation?

Comment: @curiousdannii: Looking up bowdlerisation (a term that is also new to me) it seems to mean something different (censorship on a written text). The replacements I have in mind happen in spontaneous speech. They are also at least partly conventionalized.

Comment: Bowdlerisation is also used to refer to [replacing swear words with "heck", "darn" etc](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GoshDangItToHeck?from=Main.GoshDarnItToHeck), so that sounds pretty similar to what you're asking about here.

Comment: My favorite Hungarian example is *Le van szarva...sbőrrel takarva*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you're talking about are called [minced oaths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minced_oath).

Some contemporary examples from English are *sugar* and *fudge* for *shit* and *fuck* or even the longer phrase *shut the f...ront door* for *shut the fuck up*.

Comment: To add: Two very common ones among internet people today is "fork" and "fluff", both replacements for the F-word.

Comment: You've also got fictional ones used by writers to be able to have characters swear and not have to censor it, for example Battlestar Galactica uses "Frak" as a replacement for "Fuck"